# PHP Getting the location from an IP address MaxMind GEOIP

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

I'm using `PHP MaxMind GeoIP` for getting the user's location.
I did download both files to test: `GeoLiteCity.dat` and `GeoIPCity.dat`

Here is My `php` code:

```
$ip = "189.90.207.67";
$gi = geoip_open("data/GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $ip);
print "Ip: ".$ip."<br>";
print "Country: ".$record->country_name . "<br>";
print "Region: ".$record->region. "<br>";
print "city: ".$record->city . "<br>";
print "latitude: ".$record->latitude . "<br>";
print "longitude: ".$record->longitude . "<br>";
geoip_close($gi);
```

Result:

> Ip: 189.90.207.67 Country: Brazil Region: city: latitude: -23.5477 longitude: -46.6358

The returned coordinates are different from MaxMind:
`https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo 
ip: 189.90.207.67`

The coordinates that I got in my code from my ISP, that different from
`GeoIPCity.dat` which result was empty for all fields.

Why are the results of the site and of my code different?

Comment: The demo you link to is for the paid database. This may explain the difference.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any free service that has this precision?

Answer (score 0):

The online demo is using the commercial database. Your codes are querying the GeoLite database.

You should not expect same results from two different databases.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any free service that has this precision?

Comment: Try IP2Location LITE http://lite.ip2location.com 
It has city information in the LITE database.